# Android How to upload image to server along with form fields

Tags: android, image, api, image-uploading

I recently begun working with android.

I have created registration form with some basic fields. its working fine, but here task is to upload pic along with this form fields to the server. Pic can be choose from existing or can capture with cam. Please any one suggest me best way of doing this task.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using a html form in a webview, I don't know if its the best approach, but it could work for you.

The html form will include a set of inputs, and an image upload button.
The form can then be posted to your database/other application